# Optimization with inequality constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Could someone give a solution to this problem as well as an interpretation of the results? I am not sure how to deal with inequality constraints.

Part 1:

Find the minimum value of $f(x) = |x|^2$

Subject to the constraints $ x^i \geq 0 \quad (i=1,2, ..., n) $

and $x^1 + x^2 + ... + x^n =1$

Part2:

Interpret the result geometrically.

Comment: Aren't the $i$'s meant to be indices rather than exponents? Did you mean $\lVert x \rVert^2$ (the square of the norm of vector $x$) instead of $|x|^2$?

Comment: @Jubobs That is how the question was given to me...

Answer (score 0):

For a 2D vector, the vector with minimum distance from origin is the one that is obtained by intersection of the line x + y = 1 and x = y (1/2, 1/2).

Same can be visualized for the triangle formed by 3D plane x + y + z = 1.

I am not sure but for n dimensional case it appears to be (1/n, 1/n, ... 1/n) and hence the value of f(x) = 1/n.